# How to eliminate the noise of this circuit?

Tags: noise, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential, signal-to-noise

I've built the following circuit on a PCB with reference to a [TI's solution](https://www.ti.com/pdfs/vf/medeq/informationformedicalapplications.pdf).

[image]

I changed the gain of the INA to 10 and the gain of the A3 stage to 40. I also changed the cut-off frequency of the A4 stage to 10 Hz to better suit the EMG situation (since the EMG signal has a higher frequency and a larger amplitude). My schematic is shown as below:

[image]

I tested the PCB today and found the noise from the power grid was still quite large - about 100 mV pp. And when my muscle contracts, the output would be about 800 mV pp.

I also tried to measure the CMRR of the whole circuit. I connected the 2 inputs to a 1 V, 100 Hz sinus wave signal, and found the output was also about 100 mV pp.

I'm not sure, can I say the CMRR of the whole circuit at 100 Hz is: \$ 20lg \frac{100m}{400}\$? I'm also keen to know if there is anything I can do to further improve the CMRR.

Like I saw in the solution below (from [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau516/slau516.pdf), also a solution from TI), the first stage has some bypass capacitors. Maybe I can try to add some of those? Any information would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please show your actual schematic.

Comment: Is your question about the 100mV noise?  Please add a specific question or questions.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I would like to further eliminate the noise. I've added the schematic in the question. Thanks!

Comment: "noise from the power grid was still quite large"  -- You have a some bypassing on the Vcc rail.  I would look at a better power supply, or add some series impedance to filter the noise.  The solution is based on cash and frequency of the noise.

Comment: How much bandwidth of the noise is not desirable ?When you have figured that out you can use a low pass, high pass or band pass filter.

Comment: In these circuits, the assembly technique, layout and cabling arrangement has high impact on performance - so much so that your circuit diagram is virtually useless without thorough photographic documentation of your construction. But, since you're doing EMG, why are you using E**C**G circuitry? The two are quite different and approaches from ECG will cause you unnecessary pain with EMG. An active EMG electrode with Bluetooth is FitBit-sized, and there are no wires sticking out - just two spring-loaded cylinders acting as contacts. You can use an audio Bluetooth transmitter for this too :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well... I thought EMG and ECG measurements were similar so I was trying the ECG circuitry. By the way, is the use of active electrodes almost noiseless?

Answer (score 1):

EMG is easiest done with active electrodes, with effective electrode wire lengths approximately zero. The signal amplitude is **lower** than EKG's - in fact, EKG is a cumbersome common-mode artifact in EMG acquisition!

EMG with passive electrodes with long wires is basically not done unless you want to play on hard mode for no good reason. Even back in the 60s you could use miniature low-voltage vacuum tubes to buffer EMG in a 1x2" active electrode box. This made the whole thing way less cumbersome than using long cables and associated artifacts.

EKG-specific application circuits will be *entirely inappropriate* for EMG. You don't want any far-away ground references, for one thing: EMG signals are localized. You can have a ground reference a couple inches away, or just take it from the buffered average voltage of the two input electrodes.

It is not hard to make a quiet active EMG electrode, even using ICs from 40 years ago. Virtual ground from 10-50M resistors between the input contact points about 1-2 inches apart, a CMOS buffer for both electrodes to perhaps amplify things a bit, a +/-9V battery supply. The virtual ground can be buffered and driven to the supply midpoint. No need for anything fancy really.  The rest of the processing, i.e. difference taking and additional gain, can be done at the other end of the long cable. I've built some like this in the 80s using MOS input op-amps (CA3240). These days the JFET input op-amps have those old parts handily beat :)

It basically is both harder and easier than EKG: the wires are much shorter, since the signals are much more localized, but the amplitudes are an order of magnitude smaller than in EKG (or worse), and the bandwidth needed is an order of magnitude higher - or more if you're using needle electrodes to get spikes from individual motor end units.

Also, the best diagnostic feedback for EMG signals is an audio monitor amplifier. You should be listening to them - it's much easier to debug the stuff when you hear it. With EMG, a speaker output used to be a standard feature on instrumentation, or at least a phone output. If you're not listening to it, you're missing out!

Disclaimer: I've last done EMG-from-scratch when I was a teenager. I have adult kids now, so caveat emptor.

Comment: You dont mention any pass or stop filters which makes me worry.

Comment: All I did back then was AC-coupled input and some low-pass roll-off in the gain stages. It wasn't fancy. Maybe 1st order highpass and 2nd order lowpass.